# MySQL group by strings and select in particular order

Tags: mysql, group-by

I got the following table. It is actually made up from a user and permission and a connecting relation table (users n:n groups).

```
user | permission_a | permission_b
1    | r            | rw
1    | none         | r
2    | rw           | none
3    | none         | rw
3    | r            | rw
3    | none         | none
```

As you may see the permission columns can contain rw, r and none. This is also the order of those values, meaning that rw is actually strong than r and, r stronger than none: rw > r > none.

Now, I would like to group by the user (id) and show their "strongest" permission.

So the result should look like this:

```
user | permission_a | permission_b
1    | r            | rw
2    | rw           | none
3    | r            | rw
```

Any hint on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use `MAX()` aggregate function with `GROUP BY` like

```
select `user`, max(permission_a) as permission_a,
max(permission_b) as permission_b
from permission
group by `user`;
```

Comment: This will work, however I think it's important to mention that it relies on the permissions being sorted alphabetically. In this case, `MAX` will always return rw > r > none because their 'rank' priority matches their alphabetic priority, however if you were to add a permission 'z' such that rw > r > z > none, the query would no longer work properly. Just worth noting. Given a larger set of permissions, you'd probably want to create some sort of "priority" table to join on, or assign a priority number in your query by using `CASE` statements.

Comment: I think this really works. But probably only as MAX is using alphabetical sorting wenn identifying the max value. Is there any "custom MAX" function, that would work if I got differente permissions, e.g. save > read > none?

Comment: @tyler: just what I recognized as well - any idea on how I can also ensure proper working for my other example?

Comment: @Nogga You can create a table that maps the permission strings to numbers that represent their strength (you could use the same binary representation as numeric permission modes: r = 4, w = 2, x = 1). Join with the table and get the max of the numeric strength.

Comment: @Nogga Unfortunately I may have to come back to this later! I actually am a SqlServer guy and don't ever write in MySQL, however as I said in my original comment (and Barmar said in his comment) you'd need to relate permissions to ranks and sort on those.

Comment: I'll try if I can sort it out.